# splitting field of $x^2 +1$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For $f(x) = x^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$,

I know that $f(x)$ splits in $\mathbb{C}$ as $f(x) = (x -i)(x+i),$

so it does split into linear factors. It is not a splitting field because $f(x)$ splits inside $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Is this  saying that because $(x-i)(x+i) = (x-\sqrt{-1})(x+\sqrt{-1})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i) \subset\mathbb{C}$ then $\mathbb{C}$ is not a splitting field? And because there is not smaller field than $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ for $f(x)$ to factor into, it is the splitting field?

Is this right? Also how do I know there isn't a smaller field that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ that could be my splitting field. Could I create some field smaller than $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ such that it's no longer the splitting field for $f(x)$?

Comment: $x^2+1$ doesn't split in $\mathbb Q$, and $[\mathbb Q(i):\mathbb Q]=2$, so there is no field between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(i)$

Comment: Or a different approach: the splitting field must contain both roots $\pm\mathrm i$ of the polynomial. $\mathbb Q(\mathrm i)=\mathbb Q(\mathrm i,-\mathrm i)$ being the smallest field containing both by definition must then be the smallest field in which the polynomial splits.

Comment: Since $\Bbb Q(i)/\Bbb Q$ is a normal extension, $\Bbb Q(i)$ is the splitting field of $x^2+1$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956666/show-k-alpha-is-a-splitting-field-of-text-irr-alpha-k-over-k-iff?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you for your responses. These were helpful

Comment: looking back at this, why does $[\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}]$ = 2 mean that there is no field between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$? I know if $\alpha$ is algebraic over some field and $F(\alpha)$ is the field generated by $\alpha$ over F, then $[F(\alpha):F]=deg(m_{\alpha}) = 2$ for $x^2 +1$. Does this mean theres no smaller field?

Comment: If $\mathbb Q\subseteq F\subseteq\mathbb Q(i)$, then $[\mathbb Q(i):F][F:\mathbb Q]=2$. so $F=\mathbb Q(i)$ or $\mathbb Q$

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this with an example thats of higher degree. Take $x^4 +2$. My splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i)$. Since $i \notin \mathbb{R}, [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i):\mathbb{Q}) = 2$. Since our polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})\subset \mathbb{R}, [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}):\mathbb{Q}) = 4$, then $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2},i):\mathbb{Q}) = 8$. So we know that the field has degree 8, but how do we know there is no smaller field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $x^2+1$ splits in $\mathbb Q(i)\subset\mathbb C$ but not in $\mathbb Q$,

and $[\mathbb Q(i):\mathbb Q]=2$, so there is no field between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q(i)$,

so $\mathbb Q(i)$ is the splitting field of $x^2+1$.